# How to display ID of each category in Woocommerce shop page with "Show Categories" selected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So I have my shop page set to [list all categories](https://atlantisthemes.com/woocommerce-categories/) (not products). I've been using hooks to alter the display, hide/show elements, etc.

How can I get the ID of each category in the list within that category's display? WC is obviously pulling data through the WC loop, as it displays the thumbnail and title of each category, gets the url for the category, etc. **How can I grab the ID and display it, say, next to the title for example?**

I need to know how to get the ID so that I can use that to display the value of an ACF field for each category in the list display. I assume the id will look something like `product_cat_<id-num>` or something.

Please help. Deadline is drawing near. When I Google anything related to displaying the categories on the shop page, it just gives me a bunch of links like the linked article above, which have nothing about how to extract category info from this loop...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was not passing $category to my function.

This is how you would show a custom field below a title on shop page where categories are shown:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'end_shop_loop_title_wrap', 15 );

// pass $category to function - this is what i was missing
function end_shop_loop_title_wrap($category) {

    if( is_shop() ) {

        if ( $category ) {

            $term_id = 'product_cat_' . $category->term_id;

            echo the_field( 'custom_field_name', $term_id );

        }

    }

}
```

I found the answer to my issue buried in Google on [a Stack Exchange question that I couldn't find again if i tried](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/341628/acf-under-category-name-in-shop-page) (which is why i bookmarked it).

Thanks to [Alex Uleberg](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/86050/alex-uleberg) for the answer that I found.

Why is there not more robust documentation/info/explanations for Woocommerce?